# PDO prepare statement fails

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this code to connect mysql on my php file:

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {

    function setPerson($nam, $last_n1,$last_n2, $date_birth) { //We pass all dates of the person
        include "conexion.php";
        $id_family=5;
        $id_user=1;
        $query = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO person (name, last_name1, birth_date, family_id, user_id) VALUES (name= :nam, last_name1= :last_n1,family_id=:id_family,user_id=:id_user)");
$params = array(":nam"=>$nam,":last_n1"=>$last_n1,":d_b"=>$date_birth,":id_family"=>$id_family,":id_user"=>$id_user);

 setPerson($_POST['name'],$_POST['last_name1'],$_POST['last_name2'],$_POST['d_birth']);
}
```

I take the data from ajax on my main file, I've checked that it sends correctly the values. And definitely the values are right.
It doesn't work because the query don't take the values, it isn't doing the assignment , the result sql is this:

```
INSERT INTO person (name, last_name1, birth_date, family_id, user_id) VALUES (name= :nam, last_name1= :last_n1,family_id= :id_family, user_id= :id_user);
```

but it should be (for example):

```
INSERT INTO person (name, last_name1, birth_date, family_id, user_id) VALUES ('jon', 'snow','1990-12-1',5, 1);
```

I tried to insert manually the values and it worked, I don't know why it doesn't take the values.

Comment: `name= :nam, last_name1= :last_n1,family_id= :id_family, user_id= :id_user` that whole line in invalid. Using exceptions would have caught that syntax error.

Comment: why? because that's not how it works. Read the manual. http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements and make sure you're using PDO and not `mysqli_` to connect with. Colon placeholders are PDO syntax. Read also http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php

Comment: *Nice try*, but completely wrong syntax.

Comment: I've also done that:  `$query->bindParam(':nam', $nam);
            $query->bindParam(':last_n1', $last_n1);
            $query->bindParam(":d_b",$date_birth);
            $query->bindParam(":id_family",5);
            $query->bindParam(": id_user",$id_user);
            $query->execute();` but it didn't work

Comment: Why did you edit your question without marking it as an edit under your original post? I noticed you accepted my answer, but why the  edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer as per the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30744167/1). (I also performed a rollback to the original post).

---

I'll explain graphically.

This line:

```
(name= :nam, last_name1= :last_n1,family_id= :id_family, user_id= :id_user)
```

that isn't the proper syntax for an INSERT using PDO.

Remove all of the word/equals

```
(:nam, :last_n1, :id_family, :id_user)
```

References:

- http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements
- http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php

Sidenote: You have 5 columns but using 4 in your values; one is missing or there's a column too many.

There seems to be the one missing for `birth_date` being `:d_b` so that needs to be added in your values.

```
(:nam, :last_n1, :d_b, :id_family, :id_user)
```

---

Plus, as stated in comments; make sure you're using PDO and not mysqli_ to connect with. Colon placeholders are PDO syntax.

---

Also make sure you're not faced with a variable scope.

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

after seeing that you're using custom functions.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.